# discord.py music queue system not working

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to add a queue system to my discord bot. but i am getting this output:
"Error: Unable to get information for the next song."

```
queues = {}

@bot.command(name='play')
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
async def play(ctx, *, song_name):
    server_id = ctx.guild.id
    if server_id not in server_loops:
        server_loops[server_id] = False

    file = discord.File("music.png", filename="thumbnail.png")
    wait = await ctx.send(embed=pls_wait_embed, file=file)

    if ctx.author.voice is None or ctx.author.voice.channel is None:
        await wait.edit(embed=join_first_embed)
        return

    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice_channel = ctx.voice_client

    if voice_channel is None and channel is not None:
        await wait.edit(embed=not_in_voice)
        return

    if server_id not in queues:
        queues[server_id] = []

    # Download the song information using yt_dlp
    ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': True, 'no_warnings': True}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{song_name}", download=False)
        if 'entries' in info and info['entries']:
            first_entry = info['entries'][0]
            song_name = first_entry.get('title', 'Unknown Title')
            video_link = first_entry.get('url', 'Unknown Link')
            duration = first_entry.get('duration', 0)
            queues[server_id].append({'song_name': song_name, 'video_link': video_link, 'duration': duration})
            shortened_video_link = shorten_url(video_link)  # Implement your URL shortening logic
            duration_formatted = str(round(duration / 60, 2)) + " minutes"
            now_playing = discord.Embed(
                title="Song added to queue",
                description=f"Name: {song_name} \n\nAudio link: {shortened_video_link}\n\n Song duration: {duration_formatted}",
                color=0x99ccff
            )
            now_playing.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://thumbnail.png")
            await wait.edit(embed=now_playing)

            # Check if the bot is connected to a voice channel and not playing
            if voice_channel and not voice_channel.is_playing() and not server_loops[server_id]:
                await play_next_song(ctx)
        else:
            await wait.edit(embed=discord.Embed(title="LuminaryAI - music", description=f'No results found for: {song_name}', color=0xff0000))
            return

async def play_next_song(ctx):
    server_id = ctx.guild.id
    voice_channel = ctx.voice_client

    if server_id in queues and queues[server_id]:
        next_song = queues[server_id].pop(0)
        song_name = next_song['song_name']
        video_link = next_song['video_link']
        duration = next_song['duration']
        shortened_video_link = shorten_url(video_link)  # Implement your URL shortening logic
        duration_formatted = str(round(duration / 60, 2)) + " minutes"

        # Download the next song information using yt_dlp
        ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': True, 'no_warnings': True}
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(video_link, download=False)
            if 'entries' in info and info['entries']:
                next_song_info = info['entries'][0]
                queues[server_id].append({'song_name': next_song_info.get('title', 'Unknown Title'),
                                        'video_link': video_link,
                                        'duration': next_song_info.get('duration', 0)})

                # Define a callback function to play the next song
                def play_next(e):
                    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(play_next_song(ctx), bot.loop)

                # Play the next song and set the callback
                voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(video_link, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=play_next)
                playing_embed = discord.Embed(
                    title="Now playing",
                    description=f"{song_name}\n\nAudio link: {shortened_video_link}\n\n Song duration: {duration_formatted}",
                    color=0x99ccff
                )
                file = discord.File("music.png", filename="thumbnail.png")
                playing_embed.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://thumbnail.png")
                await ctx.send(embed=playing_embed, file=file)
            else:
                await ctx.send('Error: Unable to get information for the next song.')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Queue is empty.')
```

There is a loop command which is working, So Loop command's code isn't included here.
when i use play command, the bot sends embed message and downloads the song but the song doesn't play and the loop command isn't working.